# Videos not being loaded from server

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I have a `scrollView` in which I have numerous pages (`pagingEnabled` is set to `true`). Each page contains a video which covers the entire screen and is loaded using the function you are going to find below. As mentioned, the videos are streamed from a server of mine. However I encounter a problem quite often, namely are certain videos not loaded whereas others in the same `scrollView` are. Sometimes the third is not loaded, sometimes the first one, other times two out of three are not loaded. Why would that occur?

I would really like to know how I can assure that all videos are being loaded or maybe (preferably) only one video is (pre-)loaded at a time since  I suppose it exceeds the bandwidth (the one video which is in a currently visible page or rather the video in the next page (or do I need to worry about videos needing to be cached then because videos would always have to be reloaded?))?

In addition to that, I would like to mention that every page has individual videos (which come from an array). Thus, I pass the link of each video from my class creating the `scrollView` which makes the JSON request and gets the array (`HomeController`) to the class which sets up the video (`PlayerView`) on every individual page. Accordingly, the function which sets up the video is only called after a certain variable `urlString` has been set.

### PlayerView

```
//if set call function (set in the viewcontroller `HomeController`)
var urlString: String? {

    didSet {

        setupPlayerView()

    }

}

//...

//defined here to use somewhere else...
var player: AVPlayer?

//setup video player
func setupPlayerView() {

    //check URL if can be converted to NSURL, self.urlString instead of string
    if let urlString = self.urlString, let videoURL = NSURL(string: urlString){

        //player's video
        if self.player == nil {

            player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

        }

        //add sub-layer
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.frame
        self.controlsContainerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

        //when are frames actually rendered (when is video loaded so spinner disappears)
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

        //loop through video
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                self.player?.play()
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Comment: By saying videos are not loading, what exactly do you mean? Do you see frame freeze, or black screen? Have you debugged your code? Does it get through your `if let` conditions? I don't see you're calling `play()` for your player

Comment: It does get through everything, it simply won't load the video... meaning my spinner is shown all the time with a black screen in the background (I let it wait and it turns out it does load but it takes for ever compared tot he others (3 Min), I would like to know how to load videos when they're visible and preload them if they're about to become visible because I think it is caused by how much the internet connection can take @noir_eagle

Comment: Oh, so videos do load. Do you pause other videos while you're playing current?

Comment: They do, apparently... and yes, the other videos are paused and only start on user interaction @noir_eagle

Comment: Have you checked the url by opening it in safari browser? does it load instantly or takes up to 3 mins?

Comment: Yes, in fact the video I currently load is always the same one... @noir_eagle

Comment: Is `setupPlayerView()` being called only once for each view? do you call it when the scrollView ends up on it?

Comment: And place the `self.player == nil` validation into the upper if statement, as you want to add observers and create AVPlayerLayer and insert it into the view's layer only once, when you create your avplayer

Comment: It's called whenever the string is set and this always happens immediately after the class `PlayerView` is used to put the video, spinner, etc. in each page... I put `self.player == nil` in there but nothing's changed... @noir_eagle